# Why is expressjs res.download() extremly slow?

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express app that allows downloads via special ids in the url.
Somebody can add a file, say `file.pdf` and someone else can download it via `http://app/files/<64 char id>`.

For the `files/:id` route I use res.download().

The download speed however never exceeds 300kbit/s and averages around 162kbit/s (measured with wget). This is in contrast to the 200 Mbit/s bandwidth that iperf3 reports between the two systems. The files are also placed on a ssd so access speeds should not be an issue.

The average file size is around 10 MB.

Is there any way I can speed `res.download` up or how I can implement the same app with different, more performant, expressjs functions ?

Comment: My assumption is download is possibly throttled due to some setting, which is slowing down, otherwise standard implementation would have no issue. Another option is to chunk and download via multiple Async calls, if feasible

Comment: That is something I thought of as well. Except for enabling cors there are no other settings set for express.

Comment: Did you find any more information out about the speed? I have hit a similar issue. It's looking like I may have to just defer the serving of decent sized files to nginx